# Convert SSL private key to a string

Tags: c, openssl, xmlsec

From pkcs12 file, I extracted the private key and cert using the following -
PKCS12_parse(p12, argv[2], &privatekey, &cert, &ca);

Now, I need to use the privatekey and cert to sign an XML using xmlsec libraries.

However, xmlSecCryptoAppKeyLoad() expects the key in const char* format.

How do I do the conversion?

Or, can I use xmlSecCryptoAppKeyLoadMemory() and privatekey without having to do the conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [XMLSEC-OpenSSL interface](http://aleksey.com/xmlsec/api/xmlsec-openssl-ref.html), the [xmlSecOpenSSLEvpKeyAdopt()](http://aleksey.com/xmlsec/api/xmlsec-openssl-evp.html#XMLSECOPENSSLEVPKEYADOPT) function loads an xmlsec key object from an OpenSSL `EVP_PKEY *`, and [xmlSecOpenSSLKeyDataX509AdoptKeyCert()](http://aleksey.com/xmlsec/api/xmlsec-openssl-x509.html#XMLSECOPENSSLKEYDATAX509ADOPTKEYCERT) loads an OpenSSL X509 certificate.